# Dependency Injection into a service in Laravel

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection

I have the following code which I try to create an instance of Guzzle in my service class. I am not sure what is the proper way to Inject this dependency in Laravel, this is my first time using Laravel, I have used Symfony like 8 years ago.

I get a `Runtime Exception`

`RuntimeException : A facade root has not been set.`

My code

```
namespace App\Services;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class DataForSeoService
{
    /**
     * @var \Illuminate\Http\Client\PendingRequest
     */
    private ?\Illuminate\Http\Client\PendingRequest $V3http = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->V3http = Http::withBasicAuth('xxx', 'xxx');
    }
```

Comment: Have a read through the [Laravel service container](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container#binding) documentation.

Comment: @Peppermintology I read the documentation but it's not very clear as to when and where the bindings need to happen. I feel like the issue is that I am trying to test the class from a Unit test where there is no container present. Is that the case?

Comment: ok yes that was the case, I will post an answer